# Is there an easy way to create a custom dashboard for users of the Project Portal for TFS?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

This might be a better question for https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/, but since i am using TFS there may be differences, i am not sure.

I need to create a dashboard for a couple users that outlines our current sprint queries. They only need to see kind of the same hierarchy we would see if viewing a tree view in Visual Studio's Team Explorer (when running a tree query).

Answer (score 1):

There are Sharepoint 2010 Dashboards.

Referenced [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sunder/archive/2009/11/24/reporting-in-team-foundation-server-2010-part-1-introduction.aspx)

Edit: Sharepoint 2010 configuration for compatibility explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/03/06/configuring-sharepoint-server-2010-beta-for-dashboard-compatibility-with-tfs-2010-beta2-rc.aspx) will be needed I guess.